# Blender is not using CUDA, aulthough it is configured to do so

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I'm using Pop!_OS 17.10 (based on Ubuntu 17.10) on a Dell XPS 15 9560 and Blender 2.79b. CUDA is installed, the Nvidia GPU (GeForce GTX 1050) activated and Blender is recognising both:

[image]

But when I hit render, it's rendering on the CPU:

[image]

This is my second Pop!_OS installation because I messed up the previous one. But before, Blender was rendering on the GPU as expected. Am I missing something here? How can I make this work again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on your render settings, make sure you have the rendering device set to GPU and not CPU, selecting CUDA on user preferences only enables the option to render with a GPU but you still need to change it on the render settings
[image]

Comment: Wow, now I feel really stupid :) Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: haha that happens some times, I get so stressed that I don't realize it's a 1 click solution xD, I'm glad I could help